# Is there any way to reset your stats without losing prestige/ level/ etc.?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I know that there is a "Reset All Stats" button, but I don't want to be all the way back at level one after getting tenth prestige. When I started playing MW3, I hadn't played CoD in forever, and I was a negative K/D player. Now I'm at least a 4 or 5 K/D player and I get MOABs like every other round. My K/D though is still only 1.50 :( Just wondering if it is resettable via mod or something.

Answer (score 5):

The only known way to reset your stats is to get to the maximum prestige and use a prestige token to reset yourself back to level 1.

The stats are tracked centrally as part of the [Call of Duty Elite](http://callofduty.com/elite) service, so there's no way to mod your client to change them.  Even if you could somehow break the system to change your stats, you'd probably end up running afoul of the anti-cheat systems in place.

For instance, in November 2011 [1600 cheaters were banned](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/hardware/over-1600-cheaters-banned-from-modern-warfare-3/16537) from multiplayer, and the [Robert Bowling](https://twitter.com/#!/fourzerotwo/status/137729390862802945), an employee of Infinity Ward, went so far as to say:

> [S]tats are always recorded, we can verify and detect cheating without video proof.

The bottom line is: don't mod, hack, glitch, or otherwise cheat - even to edit your stats - in Modern Warfare 3, unless you're prepared to get permanently banned.

Answer (score 1):

Reset all stats wont reset KD Ratio in game, as example, team deathmatch will still have the old KD. Too bad, i just was hoping the same and throw everything away, now a level one newby.

Answer (score 0):

Statistics are statistics is, as agent86 says the only way to reset them is to do a reset all stats.

As Brian noted most people start out badly and slowly work their way upwards, eventually your stats will level out but this does take a long time.  For example I started out pretty badly but now my weekly KD is around 2.1 but my all time KD is still around 1.9 - eventually I'll level out somewhere around 2.0 I expect.

If you truly are a 4/5 KD player (and quite frankly I doubt that having seen only 1/2 plays online ever with a genuine KD in that range) then you should level out quicker.

However everybody has games where they are unstoppable and get a ridiculous KD but your stats reflect your average, I have games where I may hit anywhere as high as a 10-20 KD (very rarely I might add) but I have far more games where I only break even or just over (plus a few negative games now and then) so in the end everything balances out.